# TYPO3 / Mask extension: How to get to work the field type "Content"?

Tags: typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, tx-mask

I've built an content element with the extension "Mask". Within this content element I use the field type "Content", with which it's possible to integrate other content elements.

But if I do that, nothing of that inline element will be rendered in the frontend, even though I select this element in the list of the allowed ones. How do I get this to work?

The fluid templates are located in an own extension/distribution (of course I changed all the paths in the mask extension ;-)) - does this take any effect?

Thank you for any hint!

Michael.

Typo3 V. 8.7.20 / Mask Extension V. 3.3.2

**UPDATE 26.11.2018**
I've made a little progress with my problem - after I add the static template of mask (I thought this will be done by my extension/distribution, but it doesn't), the output works in principle. But only the field 'header' of my nested content element will be put out in the frontend - all other field are ignored. What did I do wrong?

Attached you'll find screenshots of the affected content elements:

[image: The content element to be nested:]

[image: The wrapping content element:]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Only p Elements were rendered in the frontend! I switch the order of the template includes cleared all cashes and it worked.

[image: Order of Includes]